# Changing browser url in Nginx Unicorn Rails app on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, unicorn

Now i have a rails app configured succesfully on **Amacon EC2**.I successfully configured both nginx and unicorn and now i can see this url as `myipaddress/login`but want to access using domain name.
This is the problem as i have already changed hosts file and added the below after ssh in ec2 instance:-

```
127.0.0.1 www.mysite.com
#Virtual Hosts
myipaddress www.mysite.com
myipaddress mysite.com
```

also my `/home/ubuntu/shareit/config/nginx.conf` file looks like this:-

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/home/ubuntu/shareit/tmp/sockets/unicorn.shareit.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
  server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
  root /home/ubuntu/shareit/public;

  access_log /home/ubuntu/shareit/log/access.log;
  error_log  /home/ubuntu/shareit/log/error.log;



  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

but still whenever i try to hit the url `www.mysite.com` instead of `myipaddress/login`(which is working) i get error as **This web page is not available**.

so am i missing something?i dont want to hit my app using ipaddress.i even tried using app name in `routes.rb`,but its still not working.
i even flushed **UBUNTU dns** using `sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart` and restarted nginx and unicorn,but it doesnt works?

Any help would  be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats is the output of

```
ping myipaddress www.mysite.com
```

If it's able to resolve correctly, setup a Route53, all the configuration seems to ok, you just need a **"A"** record

Answer (score 0):

Is your domain name registered with your Server 'A' record ip?

You will need to setup an A record for your domain name to point to your server's IP address.

You can follow this link to register your domain with the server ip (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-management-console-now-supports-amazon-route-53/) provides a walk through the entire process of registering a domain at a registrar and setting it up in Route 53, including further illustrations.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer would be more useful with a longer explanation and links to helpful references. See the [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) help page.

Comment: is there no other way except using ROUTE53 ? @Sasidaran